# how to acess war/WEB-INF/classes from enclosed Ear/lib/*.jar?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, ejb, cdi, wildfly

```
  +app.ear   
       +lib  
            *.jar libraries that the war's use  
       +classes  
            *.properties and other configuration files 
       +META-INF  
            application.xml  
       jbos-app.xml  
       app.war  
       app2.war  
       appn.war
```

1. Invoking class from `lib/*.jar` of enclosed EAR  to app.war is now working.
2. When I deploy, could see two instantiations of singleton classes inside "War"(One from container and other from application).

Can we can access `war/WEB-INF/classes` from `lib/*.jar`.

Mostly it would be helpful for the websockets integration, as the serverendpoint resides on the war file.

I wanted to fetch the session of websockets and process accordingly.

### Reason behind why CDI is opted for the accessing WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib/*.jar  : [SPEC says about accessibility of classes](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly)

By default this is set to false, which allows the sub-deployments to see classes belonging to other sub-deployments within the .ear.

For example, consider the following .ear deployment:

myapp.ear
 |
 |--- web.war
 |
 |--- ejb1.jar
 |
 |--- ejb2.jar
If the ear-subdeployments-isolated is set to false, then the classes in web.war can access classes belonging to ejb1.jar and ejb2.jar. Similarly, classes from ejb1.jar can access classes from ejb2.jar (and vice-versa).

```
The ear-subdeployments-isolated element value has no effect on the isolated classloader of the .war file(s). i.e. irrespective of whether this flag is set to true or false, the .war within a .ear will have a isolated classloader and other sub-deployments within that .ear will not be able to access classes from that .war. This is as per spec.
```

---

Edit 2:

Tried all this stuff through CDI implementation based on the blog of Bruno

https://blogs.oracle.com/brunoborges/entry/integrating_websockets_and_jms_with

Faced issues on deployment of the Complete Ear file

Below class is to fire the event to the war/WEB-INF/classes/

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.enterprise.event.Event;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.websocket.Session;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Stateless
@Named
public class WebsocketMessenger {



    @Inject
    @MessageEvent
    private Event<Message> events;



     public void sendMessageToWebsockets(String rawMessage, Session session){


         RawMessageEvent rawMessageEvent = new RawMessageEvent(rawMessage, session);

 //     events.fire();

     }

 } 




   import javax.ejb.Stateless;
   import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
   import javax.inject.Named;




 @Stateless
   @Named


   public class RawMessageListener {

     public void listenToTheRawMessage(@Observes @MessageEvent RawMessageEvent rawMessageEvent){
        System.out.println("Received: " + rawMessageEvent);
     }

 }
```

Below is the exception trace:

[org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-8) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2015-03-19 11:08:39,085 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-8) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messenger': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: javax.enterprise.event.Event XXXX.HelloMessenger.events; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.enterprise.event.Event] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: javax.enterprise.event.Event XXXX.HelloMessenger.events; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.enterprise.event.Event] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 22 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got rid of the CDI event handling, Tried with the remote ejb communication for the war/WEB-INF/classes.

Its working ! , I can communicate with the classes behind the war file.

If someone have answer with CDI then it is appreciated.